# How do I fix likert() clipping of data labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, likert

I'm working with likert() to generate plots of survey data. The plots are clipping display of percentage levels, as below:

[image: image of plot]

This is more / less severe for other similar plots in the same data set (so it's just percentage symbols here, but clips into digits in other instances) - and I'm wondering if anyone has a good idea as to how to tweak this bit of likert display so that labels are within the plot grid.

```
# data for reproducible example:

q25_data <- structure(list(Q25_self_and_family = c(4, 2, 3, 5, 3, 3, 4, 2, 
4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 5, 3, 4, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 
3, 2, 5, 5, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2), Q25_local_area = c(3, 
3, 3, 5, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 5, 4, 5, 1, 4, 3, 3, 
4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
4, 3), Q25_uk = c(4, 3, 3, 5, 2, 3, 5, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
5, 4, 5, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 
2, 4, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), Q25_outside_uk = c(4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 
4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5, 3, 
3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 
-45L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# libraries:
library(tidyverse)
library(likert)

# here goes!
title <- "How serious a threat do you think \nclimate change poses to the following?"
names(q25_data) <- c("You and your family in the UK", "People in your local area or city", "The UK as a whole", "Your family and/or friends living outside the UK")
# Set up levels text for question responses
q25_levels <- paste(c("not at all", "somewhat", "moderately", "very", "extremely"),  
                    "serious")
q25_likert_table <- q25_data %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), 
                factor, ordered = TRUE, levels = 1:5, labels=q25_levels)) %>% 
  as.data.frame %>% 
  likert

plot(q25_likert_table, wrap=20, text.size=3, ordered=TRUE, low.color='#B18839', high.color='#590048') + 
  ggtitle(title) +
  labs(title = title, y="") + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = NULL)) + 
  theme_ipsum_rc() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 9))
```

Comment: If you drag your plotting window to make it wider, the clipping goes away. There is only limited room for each element. Another option is to reduce the font size of the axis labels using `theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 3))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's always the trouble when using out-of-the-box options. (:

Two quick options as with each ggplot are to expand the `limits` or to increase the expansion of the scale (via e.g. `expand = c(.1, 0)`) to make more room for the labels.

Note that `likert` uses `coord_flip` under the hood so the relevant scale is `scale_y_continuous`. By default the limits are set to -105 to 105 which I increase to -110 to 110. Also, for the labels the `abs`olute values are used.

```r
p <- plot(q25_likert_table, wrap = 20, text.size = 3, ordered = TRUE, low.color = "#B18839", high.color = "#590048") +
  ggtitle(title) +
  labs(title = title, y = "") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = NULL)) +
  theme_ipsum_rc() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 9)) 

p +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = abs, limits = c(-110, 110))
#> Scale for 'y' is already present. Adding another scale for 'y', which will
#> replace the existing scale.
```

[image]

Comment: That's great - works like a charm!